# SFMC REST API return interactions with a specific version?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I can get all interactions or single interaction via REST API 
https://www.exacttargetapis.com//interaction/v1/interactions/ and https://www.exacttargetapis.com//interaction/v1/interactions/{id}

but both of them return the **latest** version for interaction object, for example version:3

```
 {
        "id": "****************",
        "key": "****************",
        "name": "Test",
        "lastPublishedDate": "****************",
        "description": "",
        "version": 3,
        "workflowApiVersion": 1,
        "createdDate": "****************",
        "modifiedDate": "****************",
```

How can I retrieve older version for the same interaction object, for example version 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. You need to append a `versionNumber` url parameter to your route:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/{{id}}?versionNumber={{version}}
```